# Can I reply to comments via email?

Tags: trello, email, comments

Can I reply to comments via email for a card in a list, and when I see the detail of the card the emails comment is present in the comment list.

Just like replying to Google Groups post via email and it gets added as a discussion post in the Group.

Is this feature available in Trello?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently, you can request a feature by emailing feature-ideas@trello.com.

There is however a feature request already on the [Trello development board](https://trello.com/dev) for adding cards via email.

You might want to look at [Emello](http://www.emelloapp.com/) (email to Trello integration).